# play framework scheduler with Akka at server launch

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, scheduled-tasks, akka

**Question 1:** I have created a sample java application using play 2.1.1 with a scheduler to be kicked off when the application is started. I did a play compile and then play start, but i'm getting the below error, please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong here:

```
(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Play server process ID is 6160
@6edl861on: Cannot init the Global objectOops, cannot start the server.

    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:57)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:51)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:50)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.global(Application.scala:66)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.global(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:80)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.configuration(Application.scala:82)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.configuration(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.Application$class.$init$(Application.scala:268)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:383)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:228)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:259)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:258)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:258)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:46)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:46)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:46)
    at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala)
    at play.libs.Akka.system(Akka.java:25)
    at Global.<init>(Global.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:30)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:52)
```

Resources:

Global.java - in apps/

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

private Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(Global.class);

private ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(
        new Props(Retreiver.class));

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    Akka.system()
            .scheduler()
            .schedule(Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                    Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), myActor, "tick",
                    Akka.system().dispatcher());

}
}
```

Retreiver.java:

```
public class Retreiver extends UntypedActor {

private Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(TweetsRetreiver.class);

@Override
public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {

    // some code here    

}

}
```

application.conf:

```
application.global=Global
```

**Question 2**: Also, No logs are getting printed either in the console or Application.log file. I have used play.Logger package to do the logging, is this the correct package to be used to log in play 2.1.1? Please provide an example for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Problem with the line:

```
private ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(
    new Props(Retreiver.class));
```

When i moved this inside the onStart method, it got triggered correctly. Don't know why i can't define this in class level. Need to check.

Answer (score 1):

For the logging question, you have to use the [Play's Logger helper](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/Logger.html) :

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    play.Logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    ...
}
```